# Timed out waiting for URL to be accessible error in the stack trace?

Tags: testcontainers

I am using testcontainers. I have a springboot maven project . In my integration test I uses elastic search test container. I am getting an error when i run my integration test.

```
2021-03-25 13:06:29.048 ERROR   --- [           main] ?.e.c.11.2]                              : Could not start container

org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for URL to be accessible (http://localhost:32779/ should return HTTP 200)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.HttpWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(HttpWaitStrategy.java:264)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.AbstractWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(AbstractWaitStrategy.java:35)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(GenericContainer.java:892)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:440)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:325)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:323)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:311)
    at com.openmind.primecast.web.rest.MessageHistoryReportingResourceIntTest.startElasticServer(MessageHistoryReportingResourceIntTest.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)

2021-03-25 13:06:29.448 ERROR   --- [           main] ?.e.c.11.2]                              : Log output from the failed container:
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-03-25T13:06:28,166Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "968b0ad3adfb", "message": "version[7.11.2], pid[6], build[default/docker/3e5a16cfec50876d20ea77b075070932c6464c7d/2021-03-06T05:54:38.141101Z], OS[Linux/3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64/amd64], JVM[AdoptOpenJDK/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/15.0.1/15.0.1+9]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-03-25T13:06:28,169Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "968b0ad3adfb", "message": "JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk], using bundled JDK [true]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-03-25T13:06:28,169Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "968b0ad3adfb", "message": "JVM arguments [-Xshare:auto, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-16071601458555661130, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Xms31744m, -Xmx31744m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=16642998272, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=25, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=docker, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]" }

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 159.797 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.openmind.primecast.web.rest.MessageHistoryReportingResourceIntTest
com.openmind.primecast.web.rest.MessageHistoryReportingResourceIntTest  Time elapsed: 159.781 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
    at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.HttpWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(HttpWaitStrategy.java:264)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.AbstractWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(AbstractWaitStrategy.java:35)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(GenericContainer.java:892)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:440)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:325)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:323)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:311)
    at com.openmind.primecast.web.rest.MessageHistoryReportingResourceIntTest.startElasticServer(MessageHistoryReportingResourceIntTest.java:134)
```

this is how i create my test container from the Junit test.

```
   MessageHistoryReportingResourceIntTest {
        /**
         * Elasticsearch version which should be used for the Tests
         */
        private static final String ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION = "7.11.2";
    
        private static final DockerImageName ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE = DockerImageName
                .parse("docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch").withTag(ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION);
    
    @BeforeClass
        public static void startElasticServer() throws Exception {
            container = new ElasticsearchContainer(ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE);
            container.start();
    }
}
```

appreciate if you can help

thank you

Comment: Can you past your whole test class if it's not too long? Just running that piece of code works, and I don't see any issues in it.

Comment: it works in my mac book , on another environment . but in a different test machine it doesnt work.

Comment: when i tries this .   container = new ElasticsearchContainer(ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE);
  container.waitingFor(Wait.defaultWaitStrategy());
  container.start();
it is giving another error . org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for container port to open (localhost ports: [32797, 32798] should be listening). i guess they machine could be preventing from openign port

Comment: container.withStartupTimeout(Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.MINUTES));
this is working for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed by adding a delay.

```
    container = new ElasticsearchContainer(ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE);
    container.withStartupTimeout(Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.MINUTES));
    container.start();
```